# Apache Rewrite Rule to remove .php Extension adds multiple slashes

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, httpd.conf, slash

In my httpd.conf from Apache I have following code:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\s.+\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+)\.php$ /$1 [NE,R=301,L,NC]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*?)/?$ $1.php [L]
```

This URL: `http://localhost/news.php`
Becomes this URL: `http://localhost//news`

I want to remove the double slash after localhost (`http://localhost/news`). I tried many Code Snippets from other questions to remove them, but nothing worked.

Comment: remove the slash from your second `RewriteRule` statement? ( If that fails remove the slash from the first.... )

Comment: EDIT: Actually, remove the slash from after your `%{DOCUMENT_ROOT}` statement.